# Swift iOS Application Best Approach - Book With Input

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uiviewcontroller, uipageviewcontroller

I am attempting to build an application in swift that is essentially a book and some pages of this book allow for user input that is stored in the application.

I am new to swift and am unsure of the best way to approach this problem. So far I have tried using a Page View Controller and separate View Controllers corresponding to each page. The Page View Controller class navigates through the pages using Storyboard IDs to instantiate the View Controllers in an array. This works in creating a navigable book but I run into issues when trying to create outlets from the text fields on some pages since essentially the View Controller is instantiated each time its accessed and so it does not permanently exist.

I am totally and utterly lost as to where I should go from here. Any advice/wisdom will be deeply appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: PageViewController sounds like the easiest approach for you. sounds like you are having problem with the view controllers themselves. Try first maybe to create 2 or 3 view controllers, when you get to the point where you can use each and every one of them as a rootViewController, try to put them all in a PageViewController.

Comment: "but I run into issues when trying to create outlets from the text fields on some pages since essentially the View Controller is instantiated each time its accessed and so it does not permanently exist" Then you should show your actual code and ask about those issues, because that is a perfectly good way to do this.

Answer (score 2):

simplest Approach is Collection-view with pagingnation(self.collectionView.pagingEnabled = YES).
https://medium.com/@shaibalassiano/tutorial-horizontal-uicollectionview-with-paging-9421b479ee94

create multiple cell one for your Page(reading) and second for input field.

it also helps for memory management. because cell are reusable. and cell that are visible to Screen are only loaded in memory.

you can also Create Custom layout for animation as per your requirement.